# How to get Microsoft Edge instance from C#.Net

Tags: c#

How can I detect Microsoft Edge instances from C#.Net ?Currently my application is using below code to detect IE11 instances .

```
var FoundBrowsers = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();
foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer browser1 in FoundBrowsers)
    {
        if (browser1.LocationURL.ToUpper().Contains("SAMPLETEXT"))
            {
                return browser1;
            }
     }
return null;
```

How do I replace this to access MS edge instances ?

Comment: Hi have you tried Chromium ? Its Edge version of Selenium. Used for normally for automation testing.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp

Comment: As far as I know the Automation interface (ProgID "InternetExplorer.Application") has been removed or rather not been included into Edge. 
The old code where you could hook into running IE instances and their DOM starting with Shell.Windows() and do some web scrapping and data mining or automated logins etc won't work with Edge.
But as others pointed out. Selenium exists.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think direct control by code is possible like with IE. You are going to need to use the chromedriver for controller edge (which is chromium based).

If you are just looking to embed a web page into your application, you can do so with Edge's WebView2.

Comment: Correct. The best you can do is set the url and send JavaScript commands. IE used to have full COM automation so you could actually control the entire DOM through C#! (15 years before Blazor!) Those days are gone though.